# Running embark demo will not work as expected

Tags: embark

I wanted to play with embark and have a taste of dapps development, so first I tried https://framework.embarklabs.io/docs/quick_start.html

- I am working on windows 10
- I installed embark, I got version 6.0.0 installed
- Then tried *embark demo* and *embark run* as indicated in guide, the issue I got no no dashboard, and http://localhost:8000 doesn't open anything. I think, there is something missing.

This is what I got in command line when running embark run:

> C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Documents\develop\embark-projects\embark_demo>embark
> run embark info invoked
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\embark\bin\embark
> embark info located
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Documents\develop\embark-projects\embark_demo\node_modules\embark\bin\embark
> embark info Switching from embark@6.0.0 to embark@6.0.0
>
> pid 13552 listening on
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\embark-2ce1d6bc\embark.ipc
> loaded plugins: embark-ipfs, embark-swarm, embark-whisper-geth,
> embark-geth, embark-parity, embark-profiler, embark-graph,
> embark-basic-pipeline Cockpit UI available at http://localhost:55555
> Blockchain node is ready Starting Whisper node in another process HTTP
> Proxy for node endpoint ws://localhost:8546 listening on
> http://localhost:8555 WS Proxy for node endpoint ws://localhost:8546
> listening on ws://localhost:8556

Can someone help please ?

Comment: What happens if you open http://localhost:55555 in your browser?